open shell_exec in php page on Windows Server 2019 in IIS configuration
The issue is it just isn't opening, and it is telling me permission denied. I however setup the Network Administrator (he has full access to all files, folders and security driven events uch as cmd.exe) to see if this was a true statement and it seems the permission denied is not true possibly in this case.
Note I am not having any issues in my development environment using the PHP Development Environment on Visual Studio Code.
I am making a simple page where they click and it opens another page briefly to run the shell_exec then it closes and opens the ppsx related to the drop down.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'Includes/GlobalVariables.php';
    require 'Includes/Session.php';
    require 'Includes/Conn.php'; 
    require 'Includes/Redirect.php';
?>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>CI Process Program</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="icon/Hi-Temp.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <noscript>
            <p>
                This page needs JavaScript activated to work properly.<br>
                Please return here with Javascript enabled in order to open files appropriately.
            </p>
            <style>
                body {
                    display: none;
                }
            </style>
    </noscript>
    <body>
    <section class="container2">
        <?php if (!$error == ""){echo $error;} ?>
        <?php include 'Includes/BodyHeader.php'; ?>
        <form id="CIForm" method="post" target="_blank" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
            <div class="formContainer">
                <div class="formOption">
                    <select type="text" class="number" name="number" id="number">
                    <?php foreach ($pdoObj ->query($sql) as $row): 
                        $selected=($row['Part Number'] == $entry)? "selected" : '';
                        echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row["Part Number"].'">'.$row["Part Number"].'</option>';?>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button1" onclick="submitForm('OpenPPT.php')">Open PPSX</button>
                    <!--<button type="submit" name="submit" class="button2" onclick="submitForm('OpenVideo.php')">Open Demonstration Video</button>  -->
                      
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <form id="Logout1" method=post action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button3 logOnOut" id="Logout" onclick="submitForm2('Logout.php')">Logout</button>
        </form>
        <?php include 'Includes/BodyFooter.php'; ?>
        </section>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js\script.js"></script>

</html>

the page I am loading at post temporarily is here:
<?php 
session_start();
require 'Includes/Redirect.php';
$Part = $_POST['number'];
$Part = str_replace('-MS','',$Part);
$Part = str_replace('MS','',$Part);

$dir = '\\\\server\\share\\Visual Files\\';

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));
foreach ($iterator as $filename => $file) {
  $path = pathinfo($filename);
  if ($path['basename'] == $Part.'.ppsx') {
    $mainPath =  $path['dirname'];
    $ppsxFile = $path['basename'];
  }
}
if (isset($ppsxFile)){
  echo 'test';
  shell_exec('cmd.exe @cmd /C (start "" "'.$mainPath.'\\'.$ppsxFile.'")'); 
}else{
  shell_exec('cmd.exe @cmd /C (msg %username% "File "'.$Part.'.ppsx" Does not exist.")');
};
echo "<script>window.close();</script>";

The cmd.exe command runs correctly on its own on the server in the command prompt when I manually add the variables and it doesn't require and Elevated Command Prompt.
Please note I put echo 'test'; in here and on the server it will work to inspect the $ppsxFile variable is set or not depending if the file exists in the folder as programmed but the shell_exec isnt firing?  could not find any good answers online.
There are a lot of answers out there about changing the permissions (some were not for windows unfortunately).  being it seems that was the issue, I have tried many of them, including:
changing the identity in the Applicaiton Pools for the website to the network administrator account.
changing the permissions on the folders for any users in IIS.
I checked the user running the file and it is the Network Administrator.
I think there is possibly something I am missing.  I have tried this in firefox and edge browser.

You might have missed this, https://docs.lextudio.com/phpmanager/getting-started/supported-platforms#php-on-windows-status

@Lex Li. I sure did!  I will be looking into a different avenue for sure:).  Note: although it is true Microsoft will not be supporting this it says there the community would be where I go to receive support.  your link counts for me:) A person looking for this, might want a more helpful answer to their problem but I am good.

As Lex Li said, since PHP 7.x all reached end of life, PHP on Windows/IIS is no longer supported by Microsoft. So if you have any issue with PHP, you can contact  PHP community. https://www.php.net/support.php

Just updating this for future searchers.  Note my issue was not really directly related to PHP but rather the security settings of the client machines not allowing any exec to run from a browser.  thank you all.
